# Configure proguard-maven-plugin to filter META-INF of a library jar

Tags: java, maven, log4j, proguard

I am trying to use ProGuard to obfuscate my Java 8 jar.  I am having trouble configuring the ProGuard plugin in my pom.xml file in order to send the configuration that I need to ProGuard.

**BACKGROUND:**

One of my dependencies is dependent on Log4j 2.9.1.  I have run into a well documented bug in ProGuard - https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/665/.

It suggests as a workaround adding a filter to the log4j library to ignore the META-INF classes.

```
-libraryjars "log4j-api-2.9.0.jar"(!META-INF/versions/9/**.class)
```

**ISSUE:**

I have not been able to successfully configure the maven plugin to send this configuration to ProGuard.

(Note: The maven plugin is adding the -libraryjars configuration for log4j automatically because it is a project dependency.)

**FAILED ATTEMPT #1:**

I have tried adding an exclusion to prevent this library from being included automatically and a lib entry to add it with the filter.

```
<exclusions>
  <exclude>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  </exclude>
</exclusions>
<libs>
  <lib>${env.LOG4J_REPOSITORY}/log4j-api-2.9.1.jar(!META-INF/versions/**.class)</lib>
</libs>
```

The exclusion is successful but the lib entry fails.  It's being treated as a filename so the argument to ProGuard looks like

```
-libraryjars, '/mnt/juser/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.9.1/log4j-api-2.9.1.jar(!META-INF/versions/**.class)',
```

and I am getting the error

```
 [proguard] Error: Can't read [/mnt/juser/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.9.1/log4j-api-2.9.1.jar(!META-INF/versions/**.class)] (No such file or directory)
```

I tried adding punctuation to the lib declaration

```
<lib>"${env.LOG4J_REPOSITORY}/log4j-api-2.9.1.jar"(!META-INF/versions/**.class)</lib>
```

It created this argument for ProGuard

```
-libraryjars, '"/mnt/juser/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.9.1/log4j-api-2.9.1.jar"(!META-INF/versions/**.class)',
```

and failed with the following error

```
[proguard] Error: Can't read [/home/juser/working/"/mnt/juser/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.9.1/log4j-api-2.9.1.jar"(!META-INF/versions/**.class)] (No such file or directory)
```

**FAILED ATTEMPT #2**

I have tried using inclusions to explicitly add this library with a filter.

```
<assembly>
  <inclusions>
    <inclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <library>true</library>
      <filter>!META-INF/versions/**.class</filter>
    </inclusion>
  </inclusions>
</assembly>
```

The library is listed as a -libraryjars entry, but there is no filter.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the very same problem. Following configuration works for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- exclude the artifact -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>obfuscate-uber</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}-uber.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-uber.jar</outjar>
                <!-- filter out unwanted parts -->
                <inFilter>!META-INF/versions/9/**.class</inFilter>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I think in this case that the exclusion is removing the library and so the obfuscation is successful.  I think that the inFilter tag is not necessary.  The inFilter tag adds a filter to the injar and not to the libraryjars.

Comment: @mmdemirbas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900412/proguard-not-able-to-obfuscate-the-jar-through-maven-plugin Please see this. Thank U