# Proguard not able to obfuscate the jar through maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, proguard, obfuscation, proguard-maven-plugin

I am trying to obfuscate a jar build through maven, through proguard maven plugin. Build is also successful but when I decompile the same through JAD (Java decompiler), I am able to see all the java code. Thus it seems there is no obfuscation of the java source file. Please find below the pom.xml for the same :

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
    <artifactId>executable-jar-sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.testSource>1.8</maven.compiler.testSource>
        <maven.compiler.testTarget>1.8</maven.compiler.testTarget>
        <version.maven-javadoc-plugin>3.1.1</version.maven-javadoc-plugin>
        <version.proguard-base>6.1.1</version.proguard-base>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.ks.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.14</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>obfuscation-packaging</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                            <attach>true</attach>
                            <maxMemory>1024m</maxMemory>
                            <injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar> <!-- make sure to obfuscate the jar with dependencies -->
                            <proguardVersion>6.1.1</proguardVersion>
                            <appendClassifier>false</appendClassifier>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
                            <injarNotExistsSkip>true</injarNotExistsSkip>
                            <options>
                                <option>-target 1.8</option>
                                <option>-printmapping proguard.map</option>
                                <option>-verbose</option>
                                <option>-dontwarn</option> <!-- added option to ignore com.sun missing classes -->

                                <option>-overloadaggressively</option>
                                <option>-repackageclasses ''</option>
                                <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>

                                <option>-keepparameternames</option>
                                <option>-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile</option>


                                <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                                <option>-dontshrink</option>
                                <option>-dontnote</option>
                                <option>-keepdirectories</option>
                                <option>-keeppackagenames org.apache.maven.plugin.my.MyMojo</option>
                                <option>-keepnames class * implements
                                    org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo</option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembers
                                    class * implements org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo
                                    {
                                    private <![CDATA[<fields>]]>;
                                    private <![CDATA[<methods>]]>;
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepattributes
                                    Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod</option>
                                <!-- <option>-keep class com.ks.MyPlugin { *; }</option> -->

                                <option>-keep public class * {
                                    public protected *;
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keep abstract class * {
                                    public protected *;
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembernames class * {
                                    java.lang.Class
                                    class$(java.lang.String);
                                    java.lang.Class
                                    class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses
                                    class * {
                                    native <![CDATA[<methods>]]>;
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
                                    public
                                    static **[] values();
                                    public static **
                                    valueOf(java.lang.String);
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembers class * implements
                                    java.io.Serializable {
                                    static final long serialVersionUID;
                                    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[]
                                    serialPersistentFields;
                                    private void
                                    writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
                                    private void
                                    readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
                                    java.lang.Object
                                    writeReplace();
                                    java.lang.Object readResolve();
                                    }
                                </option>
                            </options>
                            <libs>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                                <!-- <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib> <lib>${java.home}/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar</lib> -->
                            </libs>
                            <dependencies>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.1.1</version>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am able to figure out what other options need to be there in so that it should obfuscate the java code.

Thanks
Kumar Shorav

Comment: 1first thing I would do is to check generated mapping file using -printmapping [filename] subsequently I will remove all -keep option to findout if proguad is acactually considering classes. Also do you see proguard logs on console

Comment: @Shailesh Thank U for your comment. Could you please explain or have some working sample that will obfuscate classes of my package only?

Comment: I don't have a running project , I will see if I can point you to github. alternatively  if you can upload a sample project with problem you are facing, I can give it a try.

Comment: @Shailesh Ok..I have already posted pom.xml. I am only checking as of now App.java having one public static void main method. and printing "Hi :".

Comment: @I used it long back in 2012 and at that time, I was able to obfuscate the java classes that hides the logic and other thing clearly. But, now after using maven plugin or through properties file, this is not working.

Comment: @Shailesh In fact I tested some of GitHub project on this, but nothing worked and when I decompile the jar, the same java code is seen. So, it is not obfuscating the java code.

Comment: an year back i did some obfuscation here https://github.com/KoolShailesh/dev

Comment: It's an old project obfuscate code but not the class names, you can check mapping file

Comment: @Kumar i am with you. nothing is generated. either the plugin really doesnt work anymore or the documentation is pretty much lacking in details how to run it.